# Error while staging packages when a Dataflow job is launched from a fat jar

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I create a maven project to execute a pipeline. If I run the main class, the pipeline works perfectly. If I create a fat jar and I execute it, I have two different errors, one if I execute it under Windows and another one if I execute it under Linux.

Under Windows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while staging packages
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElements(PackageUtil.java:364)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil.stageClasspathElements(PackageUtil.java:261)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.GcsStager.stageFiles(GcsStager.java:66)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:517)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:170)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:303)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:289)
    at ....
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: gs://MY_BUCKET/staging
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.LocalFileSystem.matchNewResource(LocalFileSystem.java:196)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.LocalFileSystem.matchNewResource(LocalFileSystem.java:78)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.matchNewResource(FileSystems.java:563)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil$PackageAttributes.forFileToStage(PackageUtil.java:452)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil$1.call(PackageUtil.java:147)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.PackageUtil$1.call(PackageUtil.java:138)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:58)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Under Linux:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to construct instance from factory method DataflowRunner#fromOptions(interface org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:233)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build(InstanceBuilder.java:162)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions(PipelineRunner.java:52)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create(Pipeline.java:142)
        at ....
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:222)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected a valid 'gs://' path but was given '/home/USER/gs:/MY_BUCKET/temp/staging/'
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.getGcsPath(GcsPathValidator.java:101)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.verifyPath(GcsPathValidator.java:75)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.validateOutputFilePrefixSupported(GcsPathValidator.java:60)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions(DataflowRunner.java:237)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid GCS URI: /home/USER/gs:/MY_BUCKET/temp/staging/
        at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.google.cloud.platform.core.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:191)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.gcsfs.GcsPath.fromUri(GcsPath.java:116)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsPathValidator.getGcsPath(GcsPathValidator.java:99)
        ... 16 more
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>xxxxxxxxxxx</groupId>
  <artifactId>xxxxxxxxx</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.dataflow/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.9.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
          <version>2.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.60</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-datastore</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>myFatJar</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation= "org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>com.myclass.MyClass</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and these are my pipeline options:

```
    ...
    DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create().as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
    //options.setGcpTempLocation("gs://MY_BUCKET/temp");
    options.setTempLocation("gs://MY_BUCKET/temp");
    options.setStagingLocation("gs://MY_BUCKET/staging");
    options.setProject("xxxxxxxx");
    options.setJobName("asd");
    options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);
    Pipeline.create(options);
    ...
```

I tried to change tempLocation with GcpTempLocation but, if I do, I have this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BigQueryIO.Write needs a GCS temp location to store temp files.
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:122)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BatchLoads.validate(BatchLoads.java:191)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$ValidateVisitor.enterCompositeTransform(Pipeline.java:621)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:651)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:655)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:655)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$600(TransformHierarchy.java:311)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:245)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:446)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.validate(Pipeline.java:563)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:302)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:289)
        at ...
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Based on the stack trace provided from the Linux environment, it doesn't look like you provided a valid GCS path: `'/home/USER/gs:/MY_BUCKET/temp/staging/'`. Somehow, the application is looking for the path in the root of the user's home directory. Do you have any indication of why this might be? Did you try explicitly adding the Apache Beam artifact for DataflowRunner to `pom.xml`?

Comment: Thank you! Replaced google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all with all its apache beam dependencies, resolve my problem!

Comment: @S.M. What version of the **google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all** dependency did you include? version 2.2.0?

Comment: @Max yes, as you can see from my pom.xml, I has previously included version 2.2.0, but I revolved my problem using beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java and the other apache beam dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

this comment resolves my question:

> Did you try explicitly adding the Apache Beam artifact for DataflowRunner to pom.xml? – Andrew

Comment: Are you able to post your resulting/full-pom here?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a second answer here, that should solve this issue more broadly.
I have a hunch that S.M.'s approach of pulling out the dependencies to the top level of the pom file above coincidentally got around the issue of not using the shade `ServiceResourceTransformer` in conjunction with the `ManifestResourceTransformer`.

However, without seeing the final pom file from S.M., I can't be certain.

Anyhow, I have included the shade build plugin configuration that worked for me:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-runner</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>${project.artifactId}${runner.suffix}</finalName>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>${runner.class}</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

**Notes:**

- I used this in conjunction with:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.0</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- I picked up the exclusion arguments from: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowSDK-examples/blob/master/java/examples-java8/pom.xml
- I had it work on both Windows and Linux